# How to install ACPYPE and fix the error in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, permissions, symbolic-link, svn

I wanted to install acpype in ubuntu 14.04 and I followed the comments given in ubuntu program installation guide: I have followed the following commands.

```
acpype
```

go to the directory in which you wish to install the program

```
svn checkout http://acpype.googlecode.com/svn/trunk acpype

ln -s $PWD/acpype.py /usr/local/bin/acpype
```

When I give this command `ln -s $PWD/acpype.py /usr/local/bin/acpype` am getting the following error:

```
sslab1@sslab1-ThinkCentre-Edge72:~/Downloads$ ln -s $PWD/acpype.py /usr/local/bin/acpype
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/acpype’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you please add the source of the instalation instructions?

Answer (score 0):

The ln -s command creates a link in `/usr/local/bin/` that points to `acpype.py` in directory you are in. Changing anything in `/usr/local/bin/` requires root privileges. You can execute a command with root privileges by putting `sudo` in front of it.

**So what this means in your case:** instead of

```
ln -s $PWD/acpype.py /usr/local/bin/acpype
```

type

```
sudo ln -s $PWD/acpype.py /usr/local/bin/acpype
```